# Perforce 2008 Upgrade to 2012

Tags: perforce, fogbugz

I am facing this problem with Perforce version upgrade from 2008 to 2012. After upgrading Perforce server (p4d) the "Checkin" link on Fogbugz system (which lists all the code check-ins happened referring a particular Fogbugz issue number) is not working correctly. Now, if I click on "Checkins" link it lists all the checkins happened but when I click on any change-list number it opens a blank browser window rather than P4Web user interface.

Please help.

Thanks.

Comment: This is probably a Fogbugz question. I know nothing about Fogbugz but I do know that the Perforce API changed a lot between 2008 and 2012. Has Fogbugz has been tested with the 2012.1 Perforce server? Which Fogbugz version works with it?